# How to search a string with pattern in all the files of a project in intelj?

Tags: intellij-idea

We have used this option( Edit -> Find -> Find in Path) to search a string using IntelliJ. Currently, if we type to search a string, it will return the lines which contain the given string. But I want to find the lines which contain the given string and/or some pattern. Is there such a facility available in IntelliJ Idea?

Assume, We are going to search a string from the below lines

Test123456

Test12345

Sampletest12356

Search String:  test*6

Expected output: Test123456

Search String: *test*6

Expected output: Test123456 , Sampletest12356

Comment: There's a "Regex" checkbox when finding in path. Would just checking that box and searching for a regex solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should turn on the "Regex" checkbox and type in a proper regular expression in the search field, that's all. If I understood correctly, for your examples the correct requests would be `test.*6` and `.*test.*6` respectively.

[image]